# Streaming data access and latency in hadoop applications

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am very much new to hadoop and going through the book 'Hadoop the definitive guide'

What is meaning of Streaming data access in Hadoop and why we say latency is high in Hadoop applications.   Can anyone please explain me ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Ok..Let me try.."Streaming data access" implies that instead of reading data as packets or chunks, data is read continuously with a constant bitrate, just as water from a tap. The application starts reading data from the start of a file and keeps on reading it in a sequential manner without random seeks.

Coming to the second part of your question, latency is said to be high in Hadoop applications as the initial few seconds are spent in the activities like job submission, resource distribution, split creation, mappper(s) creation etc.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Tariq.. your answers makes sense... I have one more question based on the answer of latency...
As you said and rightly explanined that Latency is high..because there is some initial overhead involved in Map reduce jobs....
But we are using hadoop/MapReduce because its faster way of doing Big-data analysis as compared to other existing  alternatives we have of doing the same....Am I right ?

Comment: sorry for the late response. "Faster" is actually an ambiguous word when it comes to BigData. Let me put it like this..what would you choose if you have to stitch a piece of cloth V/S going on a war. You would definitely pick a needle in the former case and a sword in the latter. if you pick up the needle and start fighting you would keep on fighting for ages and loose eventually. same with hadoop. Fast in terms of Hadoop means processing TBs of data in a relatively very small time(maybe a few hours) and not processing a few MBs in milliseconds. consider processing 5PB data stored in MySQL

Answer (score 2):

For **latency**, I can say that the completion time is always more than **30 sec**, even if you are working with **KB's** of data. I don't totally know why it is so long but this time is initializations, e.g creating job, determination that which part of data is going to be processed by which worker, and so on.

So, if you are going to be working on small amount of data that is less than GB's, then don't go for hadoop, just use your pc. *Hadoop is only good for big data*

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the fact that HDFS operations are read-intensive as opposed to write-intensive. In a typical scenario source data which is what you would use for analysis is loaded into HDFS only when it is up-to-date and to ensure you have the latest data set.

During analysis, a copy of the original data (in almost its entire form) is made. Your MapReduce operation will then be invoked on the copied data.

As you can see it is different to the usual relationship between storage and processing. In normal operations (think your PC/Mac) you would ideally want the files to open quickly, which is low latency and maintain small file sizes to make that feasible.

Since HDFS inclines itself to working with petabytes (1000s of GBs) latency will be high but in contrast it is realistically possible to work with large data sets much more easily.